# Український відповідник до слова "скриншот"

Tags: переклад, вживання-слів, from-english

[Англійсько-український словник з ІТ 1999–2011рр.](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=screenshot&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on)

> screenshot = знімок екрана

[Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/skrinshot) пропонують замінювати слово ***"скріншот"*** на відповідники

> *зняток, знімок екрану, екранка, знимка.*

***"зняток"*** має найбільшу кількость голосів, проте в словниках не знайшла.

Яке слово нормативно вживати в значенні screenshot?

Comment: https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0&scope=ukr&main_only=on&dicts=15
https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA&scope=ukr&main_only=on&dicts=15
Тлумачно-стилістичний словник української мови

Comment: Див. також інше запитання: [«Як нормативно „скриншот“ чи „скріншот“»](/q/4562). Можливо, їх варто було б об'єднати в одне, але вони за змістом різні: це про правопис прямого запозичення, а те про спроби пошуку «ріднішого» еквівалента.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Словників як таких, на жаль, не знайшла, оскільки слово "скриншот" є відносно новотвором. Єдиною працею, в якій зафіксоване це слово із можливим відповідником, є [Тлумачно-стилістичний словник української мови, 2013](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on), що вище у коментарях був запропонованим п. muffin:

> **Зня́ток**, -тка, чол. - 3. комп., новотвір. Те ж саме, що й **скріншо́т**.

Однак щодо різних сайтів, то вони пропонують здебільшого саме цей відповідник. Про це дізнаємося на [forum.meta.ua](http://forum.meta.ua/topic/t/160341/asc/0.html):

> **ЗНЯТОК** - **скріншот**, прінтскрін; скан (сканована сторінка)

[Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0):

> Знімок екрану (англ. screenshot, скриншот, **зняток**)

[kolomyia.today](https://kolomyia.today/vpodobajka-lazivka-ta-golyarnya-krasyvi-ukrayinski-slova-yaki-zaminyat-populyarni-zapozychennya-14416) та ін.:

> скріншот – **зняток**

Comment: Додам, що за словником родовий відмінок має бути «екран**а**», а не «екран*у*» — але у Вікіпедії на сторінці наразі обидва варіанти (мабуть, це помилка).

Answer (score 3):

В українському інтерфейсі macOS використано термін "знімок екрана":

[image: знімок екрану налаштувань комбінацій клавіш]